# Como direciono o link para a âncora e fecho o modal ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: javascript, html, react, modal, ancora

Tenho alguns links num modal feito em React que vão para âncoras da página que o modal foi aberto. Estou usando href para a âncora e o evento onClick para fechar o modal. Exemplo:

```
<a onClick={props.onHide} href="#denuncias">
```

Porém, um anula o outro. Quando tenho o evento, a âncora não funciona, quando tiro o onClick, a âncora funciona, porém o modal não fecha.

**Programação do modal:**

```
const MyOwnModal = (props) => {
return (
    <Modal
    {...props}
    size="lg"
    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
        POLITICA DE PRIVACIDADE
      </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
```

**Programação do onHide:**

```
<MyOwnModal
            show={modalShow}
            onHide={() => {
              if(window.location.hash){
                setModalShow(false);
            }}}
          />
```

Anteriormente, eu não tinha adicionado este if no onHide. O adicionei buscando informações na internet, mas não ajudou muito. Com ele, o modal só fecha direcionando para a âncora na primeira vez.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando diretamente o `window.location` (nem sempre comum num app react), você pode navegar para uma âncora usando diretamente

```
window.location = '#some-hash'
```

O modal pode receber um `onSectionSelected`, que fecha o modal e devolve um section/hash para então navegar.